# How to make recursive functions calls in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I want to update `taskId` and `workerId` in `databaseCheck` that we are getting from `getData` call. after `caseIdFound` i am invoking `completeTask` than again in `dbFactory` i have to execute `getData` again for new `taskId` and `workerId` because everytime `completeTask` method invoked it needs new taskId and workerId for api.

what would be best approach in this case ?

ctrl.js

```
function getData() {
    Factory.then(function(response) {
        datbaseCheck(response.data);
    })

}

function databaseCheck(data) {
    var taskid = data.id;
    var workerId = data.workerId;
    if (data.caseIdFound === true) {
        completeTask(taskid, workerId);
        dbFactory(data).then(function(response) {
            // Here i want to call again getData() function to get updated taskid and workerId.
            completeTask(taskId, workerId);
        })
    }
}

function completeTask(taskid, workerId) {
    Factory(taskid, workerId).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });

}
```

Comment: look into how to chain promises.

Comment: this is client side implementation.

Comment: you'll need some `return`s in there in order to get your promises working.